# Unable to access content of window with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have to click a button that opens a window, and I want to retrieve the content of that window like so:

```
String master = browser.getWindowHandle();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@title=\"Quitter la session du portail actuelle et fermer la session\"]"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
Set<String> handles = browser.getWindowHandles();
for ( String handle : handles ) {
    if(!handle.equals(master)) {
         browser.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}
System.out.println(browser.getPageSource());
```

The window does open correctly upon click, however, the console output reads:

```
null
```

I can tell that I can point to the window, because closing it works:

```
String master = browser.getWindowHandle();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@title=\"Quitter la session du portail actuelle et fermer la session\"]"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
Set<String> handles = browser.getWindowHandles();
for ( String handle : handles ) {
    if(!handle.equals(master)) {
         browser.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}
browser.close();
```

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong, I can't manipulate the elements inside the window since I can't access it.

Edit:

URL of the new window: `https://thatwebsite.fr/com.sap.portal.navigation.masthead.logoffConfirmMsg`

HTML from new window:

```
<table datatable="0" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="ctrlMsgBarImgWarning">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="ctrlTxtStd">Are you sure you want to log off?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" nowrap="" colspan="2">
                <a id="htmlb_465_htmlb_162_1" ct="B" title="Yes" st="" href="javascript:void(0);" ti="0" tabindex="0" class="urBtnStd" usedclasses="urBtnStdDsbl urBtnStdD urBtnStdDDsbl" ocl="if (htmlbButton_checkClick('htmlb_465_htmlb_162_1', event)) {return htmlbDoEvent(this,'C','onclick','0','htmlb_465_htmlb_162',1,1,'',0);}" onkeydown="return ur_Button_keypress(event)" onclick="return ur_Button_click(event);" style="text-align:center;overflow:visible;">Yes</a>
                <a id="htmlb_465_htmlb_162_2" ct="B" title="No" st="" href="javascript:void(0);" ti="0" tabindex="0" class="urBtnStd" usedclasses="urBtnStdDsbl urBtnStdD urBtnStdDDsbl" ocl="if (htmlbButton_checkClick('htmlb_465_htmlb_162_2', event)) {return htmlbDoEvent(this,'C','onclick','0','htmlb_465_htmlb_162',2,1,'',0);}" onkeydown="return ur_Button_keypress(event)" onclick="return ur_Button_click(event);" style="text-align:center;overflow:visible;">No</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I'm basically trying to do is click the `Yes` button.

Comment: Did you try to interact with any element  on newly opened windows , since you have mentioned that you are able to close it ?

Comment: Please provide some HTML source.

Comment: @cruisepandey yes I have, it's unable to find any element in the page, the only thing I'm able to do so far is close it

Comment: @Kovacic of the new window?

Comment: @Meryem : Can you share the URL or HTML or newly opened window ?

Comment: sure, provide as many information You can.

Comment: @cruisepandey I updated the post with the info

Comment: try with this after opening the new window : `new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Yes"))).click()`

Comment: unfortunately , the URL you have shared is not working.

Comment: @cruisepandey yes that exactly what I tried but it gives a `java.lang.NullPointerException`in that line. That URL is only available localy

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this :

After click on button/links on first page :

```
ArrayList<String> windows = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());  
driver.switchTo().window(windows.get(1));  

new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Yes"))).click()  
driver.close();  
driver.switchTo().window(windows.get(0));  //This is switch to windows where you left off
```

Comment: Just like the othe solution it gives a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error on the clicking Yes button line

Comment: @Meryem : Is there anything related to initialization of any object in your code. I suspect that would be the issue, since you are getting NullPointer exception.

Comment: I only get the NullPointer when I try to interact with the new window element, and they're all in the code I have posted

Answer (score 0):

I think you were pretty close. You need to wait for the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of the *New Window* to be rendered (*you can wait for the button with text as **Yes** to be clickable*) and you can use the following solution:

```
String master = driver.getWindowHandle();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@title=\"Quitter la session du portail actuelle et fermer la session\"]"))).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
for ( String handle : handles ) {
    if(!handle.equals(master)) {
     driver.switchTo().window(handle);
     new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='urBtnStd' and starts-with(@id,'htmlb_')][contains(.,'Yes')]")));
     System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
    }
}
```

**Note**: Ensure that the webdriver instance in this solution is **driver** (not *browser*)

Comment: Like the other answers I have tried, this gives me a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error in the line where I click on the Yes button

Comment: Nopes, we are not attempting any `click()` as such on the **Yes** button. We are simply waiting before extracting the page source.

Comment: @Meryem Checkout my updated answer and let me know the result.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is still a NullPointerException

Comment: Can you update the question with your full code block for further analysis?

Answer (score 0):

This window is a modalDialog, isn't it? If it is a modal dialog, so you can find an element by selenium but cannot get any attributes of it.

For details:
Modal pop-up - This is very specific to IE, Microsoft defined it as

When Windows Internet Explorer opens a window from a modal or modeless HTML dialog box by using the showModalDialog method or by using the showModelessDialog method, Internet Explorer uses Component Object Model (COM) to create a new instance of the window. Typically, the window is opened by using the first instance of an existing Internet Explorer process. When Internet Explorer opens the window in a new process, all the memory cookies are no longer available, including the session ID. This process is different from the process that Internet Explorer uses to open a new window by using the open method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759(VS.85).aspx

MSDN blog on Modal dialog

When user select Model popup, parent window is blocked waiting for the return value from the popup window. You will be not able to see the view source of the page, need to close the popup then only the parent window is activated.

How to get object properties of the model-popup? Copy the popup URL and open in a new TAB, then it will display in normal window format, where you can use IE Dev Toolbar or FireBug to capture properties.